# Error in code running a function over several varaibles, where is the error?

Tags: r

There is some error when running the function pvalues, but I dont know whats wrong. I guess it is something with (). Can anyone see it? Or is the problem you cant run sapply over several rows? in that case, how would you do it?

```
set.seed(1)
  id <- rep(1:3,each=4)
  trt <- rep(c("A","OA", "B", "OB"),3)
  pointA <- sample(1:10,12, replace=TRUE)
  pointB<- sample(1:10,12, replace=TRUE)
  pointC<- sample(1:10,12, replace=TRUE)
  test <- data.frame(id,trt,pointA, pointB,pointC)
  test

  pvalues <- sapply( test[,3:5] , FUN = function(x) 
    dflmer <- lmer(test[,x] ~ (1|id) + trt, data=test
    printanov <- Anova(dflmer, type=3)
    printanov$`Pr(>Chisq)`[[2]]
    )
    data.frame(pvalues)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need curly brackets with multiple lines in an `sapply`. Code below should work. Also the `test[,x]` is redundant, use `x`.

```
pvalues <- sapply(test[,3:5], FUN = function(x) {
  dflmer <- lmer(x ~ (1|id) + trt, data=test)
  printanov <- Anova(dflmer, type=3)
  printanov$`Pr(>Chisq)`[[2]]
})
```